# JSF Single line error: SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I am getting that error for **NO** reason.

```
com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Above error printed as complete error log by application server, there is not any stack trace or anything else. I have switched to debug log mode for WebLogic but nothing else printed.

Obviously I have done sth. that causes this internal error but can not find any reason.

Log is printed just after that statement:

```
return "pm:searchResultMap";
```

That statement refers to navigation command to another page. `searchResultMap` is the ID of the page that is wanted to browse:

```
<pm:view id="searchResultMap">
```

Also browser log says nothing. This is an emergency and I am really going crazy! Maybe this is about page structure:

```
<!-- 
    author:  Ömer Faruk Almalı

     -->
<pm:page>
<pm:view id="searchResultMap">
<pm:header >
    <turkcell:header/>
</pm:header>
<h:form id="map_content">
<pm:content>
<p:layout>
//content//
</p:layout>
<turkcell:footer name="searchResultMap"/>
</pm:content>
</h:form>
</pm:view>
</pm:page>
</f:view>
```

*WebLogic 10.3.4.02, Javax Faces 2.1.11, PrimeFaces 3.3.1, PrimeFaces Mobile 0.9.3, Windows 7 Professional*

Comment: Your page appears to end half way through a tag...

Comment: Try to isolate the problem in a single view with nothing more that the most basic elements that can help you to reproduce it. After doing this, share the code so we could reproduce it as well and give you a hand.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am aware that I didn't share a valid xhtml code. Cause sharing internal company sources is not allowed. I am also sorry about that. But if you have an ideas or clues about why JSF throws kinda exception I can edit page in a proper(!) way and share with you.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı: I suggest you try to cut down the page until you have a short but *complete* page which demonstrates the problem. (Take a copy of the "real" broken code, then remove one bits at a time until you're left with nothing but the problem - that won't be "internal company source" at that point.)

Comment: Is that during an ajax request? If so, look at the response body in browser's HTTP monitor. Otherwise, install an `ExceptionHandler` so that you've the opportunity to log the exception. Or, just put a breakpoint in the debugger and look at the stack trace of the caught exception :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for valuable suggestion, actually I have solved problem with courtesy of your suggestion and found a `p:message` component that violates whole page.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for suggestion, yes exception thrown during an ajax request. It seems I should define an exception handler that catches exceptions which is absorbed by JSF or PrimeFaces.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for help, I've solved via that kinda way.

Comment: @Ömer: this is maybe helpful: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı Hi, I've seen your post because i've faced the same problem. And solve it based on the comments. So you should add an answer it will help other users like me :)